# How to filter empty string from MongoDB using Spring Boot JPA query method keywords

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

I am trying to find all appointments that ID is not empty string and not null but can't figure out what the methods are.

Here's my repository method:

```
findByAppointmentIdNotNullAndAppointmentIdNot(String condition);
```

Internal Server Error

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'appointmentId' expression specified as 'appointmentId : Document{{$ne=}}'. Criteria already contains 'appointmentId : Document{{$ne=null}}'.
```

Using NotNull and Not keywords here, and pass empty string as condition, unfortunately the result still contains appointment which appointment id is empty string. Can some help?

Comment: did you try to replace your repository method to findByAppointmentIdNotNullAndNot(String condition);